# Set Timezone offset programatically in AnyTime datepicker

Tags: javascript, anytime

I've been using AnyTime datepicker: http://www.ama3.com/anytime/ and I now need to set the TimeZone and update AnyTime datepicker with javascript. Only I can't seem to find the option to do this, And I'm not exactly a Javascript Hero.

I think I've narrowed it down to the function `askOffset: function( event )` on line `1919` But can't exactly figure it out what to do next. I don't know what the abbreviated variables mean and I've been randomly trying things and can't figure it out.

The reason I'm doing this is because I have the select dropdown somewhere else on the screen (looks fancier) and I also want the ability to load the saved timezone from cookies.

I've also found some documentation that might be useful: `utcFormatOffsetImposed` and `utcParseOffsetAssumed` on the AnyTime page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picker automatically parses the timezone from the value in the input field, so if you want to set a specific timezone, just initialize the input field with a value that uses the same timezone.

`utcFormatOffsetImposed` and `utcParseOffetAssumed` can be used to force specific time zone conversion in `AnyTime.Converter`, so if you want to use the converter to initialize the field, you can do something like this:

```
<input type="text" id="myField"/>
<script>
$(function(){
var myFormat = '%r %@';
var myConv = new AnyTime.Converter({format:myFormat});
myConv.utcFormatOffsetImposed( -330 );
$('#myField').
  AnyTime_picker({format:myFormat}).
  val( myConv.format(new Date()) );
});
</script>
```

Of course, replace the format string with whatever you want, as long as it contains `%#`, `%+`, `%-`, `%;`, `%;` or `%@` for the timezone information.